# how to import a hive adapter in flutter

Tags: flutter, import, flutter-hive

I created a flutter project and need to save data to the device with complex object

### The complex object

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'expense_item.g.dart';
// run flutter packages pub run build_runner build

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class ExpenseItem {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String name;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String amount;
  @HiveField(2)
  final DateTime dateTime;

  ExpenseItem({
    required this.name,
    required this.amount,
    required this.dateTime,
  });
}
```

I generated successfully expense_item.g.dart file

now after my main.dart i need to import the ExpenseItemAdapter but it is not recognised

```dart
void main() async {
  // init hive
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  // register adapter
  Hive.registerAdapter(ExpenseItemAdapter);
  // open hive box
  await Hive.openBox('expenses_database');

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

what to do

Answer (score 1):

You must put an open and closed parenthesis in front of ExpenseItemAdapter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).